# Problema con pagina web hecha en C# y ASPX

Tags: html, c#, visual-studio, aspx

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice esta pagina web utilizando html, c# y APSX para subirlo a un servidor oracle
pero me sale este error de que la primera linea esta mal por que no encuentra UI del Default.aspx.cs, este esta asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va en formato texto, siempre.

Comment: En que version estas haciendolo???

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.